# SQLAlchemy: Counting multiple relationships - best way?

Tags: sqlalchemy, count, orm, relationship

Imagine the following (example) datamodel:

```
class Organization(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    friendly_name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    users = db.relationship('Users', back_populates='organizations')
    groups = db.relationship('Groups', back_populates='organizations')

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    organization_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('organizations.id'))
    organizations = relationship("Organization", back_populates="users")

class Group(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    organization_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('organizations.id'))
    organizations = relationship("Organization", back_populates="groups")
```

(so basically an Organization has User and Group relationships)

What we want is to retrieve the counts for users and groups. Result should be similar to the following:

| id | friendly_name | users_count | groups_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | o1 | 33 | 3 |
| 2 | o2 | 12 | 2 |
| 3 | o3 | 1 | 0 |

This can be achieved with a query similar to

```
  query = db.session.query(
        Organization.friendly_name,
        func.count(User.id.distinct()).label('users_count'),
        func.count(Group.id.distinct()).label('groups_count'),
    ) \
        .outerjoin(User, Organization.users) \
        .outerjoin(Group, Organization.groups) \
        .group_by(Organization.id)
```

which seems quite overkill. The first intuitive approach would be something like

```
  query = db.session.query(
        Organization.friendly_name,
        func.count(distinct(Organization.users)).label('users_count'),
        func.count(distinct(Organization.groups).label('groups_count'),
    )# with or without outerjoins
```

which is not working (Note: With one relationship it would work).

**a) Whats the difference between `User.id.distinct()` and `distinct(Organization.users)` in this case?**

**b) What would be the best/most performant/recommended way in SQLAlchemy to get a count for each relationship an Object has?**

**Bonus)**: If instead of `Organization.friendly_name` the whole Model would be selected (`...query(Organization, func....)`) SQLAlchemy returns a tuple with the format t(Organization, users_count, groups_count) as result. Is there a way to just return the Organization with the two counts as additional fields? (as SQL would)

Answer (score 1):

**b:**

You can try a window function to count users and groups with good performance:

```py
  query = db.session.query(
        Organization.friendly_name,
        func.count().over(partition_by=(User.id, Organization.id)).label('users_count')
        func.count().over(partition_by=(Group.id, Organization.id)).label('groups_count')
    )
    .outerjoin(User, Organization.users)
    .outerjoin(Group, Organization.groups)
```

**bonus:**

To return count as a field of `Organization`, you can use [hybrid_property](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html), but you would not be happy with the performance.